# How to get the instance id from within an ECS instance?

Tags: alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs

In the Alibaba cloud Enviroment, how to find  out the instance id of an ECS instance from within the ECS instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps for Linux Instance

1. [Connect to a Linux instance by using a password.](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/25434.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.a3.2.4c7959224JaI7x#concept-rsl-2vx-wdb)
2. Run `curl http://100.100.100.200/latest/meta-data/` to access the root directory of the metadata.
3. Add the specific metadata name to the preceding command to access the specified metadata. For example:
    Run `curl http://100.100.100.200/latest/meta-data/instance-id` to get the ID of an ECS instance.
    Run `curl http://100.100.100.200/latest/meta-data/image-id` to get the image ID of an ECS instance.

For Windows Instances

1. [Connect to a Windows instance.](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/25435.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.a3.3.4c7959224JaI7x#concept-n31-wyx-wdb)
2. Use PowerShell to run `Invoke-RestMethod http://100.100.100.200/latest/meta-data/` to get the metadata.
3. Add the specific metadata name to the preceding command to access the specified metadata. For example:
    Run `Invoke-RestMethod http://100.100.100.200/latest/meta-data/instance-id` to get the ID of an ECS instance.
    Run `Invoke-RestMethod http://100.100.100.200/latest/meta-data/image-id` to get the image ID of an ECS instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can run this query for **Linux ECS**

```
curl http://100.100.100.200/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```

For **Windows ECS** use PowerShell and execute the following code

```
Invoke-RestMethod http://100.100.100.200/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```

Source: https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/49122.htm

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you have the OpenSSL configured in your ECS instance before issuing the commands.

You can get the instance ID of Linux ECS instance by issuing the following command:

```
curl http://100.100.100.200/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```

For Windows ECS instance use Powershell:

```
Invoke-RestMethod http://100.100.100.200/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```